# Angular RouteGuard / Dynamic Navigation

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an application where my navigation bar changes based off what 'area' of the product they are in. I am using Angulars Route Guards to make sure that their access is checked so they can only hit the routes they have access to. This works great!

Within my `app-routing-module.ts` I am (trying) to be smart and leverage the ActivatedRouteSnapshot to obtain all the child links and then build out a navigation be for it. What I would like to do, is also use the Route Guard to decide if the child link should even be displayed or not.

// Guard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { MeService } from '../shared/services/me.service';

@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _meService: MeService) {}
  async canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    const user = await this._meService.getCurrentUser();
    if (user && user.isUserAdminForCompany) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

// Routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'route1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'route1', component: MyComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'overview', component: Overview },
      { path: 'specs', component: Specs, canActivate: [ AdminGuard ] }
    ]
  }
];
```

So, once someone hits `MyComponent`, I fetch the child routes and make a navbar out of it. Is it possible to have some kind of directive or some sort to leverage the `AdminGuard` on the `/spec` path to hide the URL if the `AdminGuard` returns false? Since some/more of my guards require some sort of async call to the server or some other service dependency, I can't just simply call `guard.canActivate` within an `*ngIf` or something.

I'm pretty sure it doesn't exist, but it seems like need some kind of setup like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="child.path" [canActivate]="child.guards">{{child.name}}</a>
```

**UPDATE**
I ended up just opening a GitHub Feature Request on the angular repo. This functionality doesn't seem to be present (in an out of the box way). Until a better solution is found, I'm just going to make a custom directive that will run the logic in the Guards to evaluate if something should be exposed or not.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I eventually went with. Since there isn't any 'out of the box' way to leverage guards for what I wanted to do, I just made a custom directive.

The one thing I'll note about this solution is that I hate two of the following things (which I'll change eventually).

1. If your Guards have anything that does a redirect, you'll have to change it so the Guard only returns true/false. If it redirects the page on Guard failure, then the directive will just end up redirecting you instead of just hiding the element
2. `this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = hasAccess ? 'block' : 'none';` There's a better solution to this than just doing a simple hide. It should act like `*ngIf` where it doesn't even render the element at all unless it evaluates to true.

Implementation:

```
<div appGuard [guards]="myGuardsArray">Something you want to hide .... </div>
```

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Injector, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appGuard]'
})
export class GuardDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() guards: any[];
  private readonly _elementRef: ElementRef;
  private readonly _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;
  private readonly _router: Router;
  private readonly _injector: Injector;
  constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, _router: Router,
              _injector: Injector) {
    this._elementRef = _elementRef;
    this._activatedRoute = _activatedRoute;
    this._router = _router;
    this._injector = _injector;
  }
  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    const canActivateInstances = this.guards.map( g => this._injector.get(g));
    const results = await Promise.all(canActivateInstances.map( ca => ca.canActivate(this._activatedRoute.snapshot, this._router.routerState.snapshot)));
    const hasAccess = results.find( r => !r) === false ? false : true;
    this._elementRef.nativeElement.style.display = hasAccess ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

A simple solution to figure out how to handle redirects or not:

```
async canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    const user = await this._meService.getCurrentUser();
    const result = user && user.isUserAdminForCompany;
    if (next.routeConfig && next.routeConfig.canActivate.find( r => r.name === 'NameOfGuard') && !result) {
  window.location.href = `${environment.webRoot}/sign-in`;
}
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just add below code in one function and pass that function in *ngIf in the same component where you have your routerLinks.

```
const user = await this._meService.getCurrentUser();
if (user && user.isUserAdminForCompany) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

That will solve your problem. Just slight change in approach this will hide the router links itself

Comment: Because that violates DRY (Do Not Repeat Yourself) and also introduces an uneccessary overhead of managing the logic to resolve permissions and roles in different locations. Since this is the scope of what Guards were designed for, it would be nice to expand that feature down to a directive (which is the route I'm taking. I'll post an answer soon)

Comment: No It wont i guess.. As per my understanding you want to navigate user only if that user has admin previllages right? You can achieve this either by blocking through gaurd or By hiding them from that user. So by my solution you wont require your gaurd anymore so There is no code repeat

Comment: The admin part is just a basic example. The application will eventually end up with a lot more guards needed (for different levels of permissions, different product access, etc...). So, having the ability to centrally manage logic to decide if someone has access to something is paramount.